# Appending a big list of lists / Web scraping [Python]

Tags: python, python-2.7, xpath, web-scraping, lxml

I am pretty new to python but not so lazy when it comes to debugging; I hope some of you already had a similar problem, even though I couldn't find anything on forums yet.

My project:

- Scrape a few websites with Request & Lxml and write my tree.XPath result to a list of lists ([list of stocks, list of prices, list of time],...)

My problem:

- Appending the lxml tree to my list of lists, after a certain amount of loops (my functions are being called in a while true loop)

My suspicion:

- The maximum size of list seems to be in the 500.xxx.xxx elements range. I am having 3*247*Number of loops, and it always crashes at 313 loops! So I am having close to 1.xxx.xxx elements, so size shouldn't be a problem. But then why should it always crash at a constant number of loops? :(

My solving attempts:

- Emptying my list of lists works, though I don't really want my "database" to be deleted
- Copying my list of lists to another variable and emptying my first variable does not work. The program just stops, even though it's in a while 1 loop
  just stepping over with pass = the program keeps going into the except!

Things I don't really understand:

- When I have no error handler, I have an error report about an html parse error. Why should parse error only happen at 313 loops?

Error:

```
File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 706,
    in lxml.etree._handleParseResult (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:106817)
File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 644,
    in lxml.etree._raiseParseError (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:105874)
File "<string>", line 1
    lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: line 1: switching encoding: encoder error
```

My code:

```
from lxml import html
import requests, datetime, time, smtplib

def getkurse(m_kurse):
kurse = [[],[],[]]

url=[]
url.append('http://www.finanzen.net/aktien/Deutschland-Aktien-Realtimekurse')
url.append('http://www.finanzen.net/aktien/Deutschland-Aktien-Realtimekurse@intpagenr_2')
url.append('http://www.finanzen.net/aktien/Deutschland-Aktien-Realtimekurse@intpagenr_3')
url.append('http://www.finanzen.net/aktien/Deutschland-Aktien-Realtimekurse@intpagenr_4')
url.append('http://www.finanzen.net/aktien/Deutschland-Aktien-Realtimekurse@intpagenr_5')
url.append('http://www.finanzen.net/aktien/Deutschland-Aktien-Realtimekurse@intpagenr_6')
url.append('http://www.finanzen.net/aktien/Deutschland-Aktien-Realtimekurse@intpagenr_7')
url.append('http://www.finanzen.net/aktien/Deutschland-Aktien-Realtimekurse@intpagenr_8')
url.append('http://www.finanzen.net/aktien/US-Aktien-Realtimekurse')

for x in range(0,len(url)):
    page = requests.get(url[x])
    page.encoding="utf-8"
    tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
    underlying = tree.xpath('//div[@field="ask"]/text()/parent::*/parent::*//parent::*/td[@class="text-left"]/a[position()=2]/text()')
    ask =tree.xpath('//tr/td/div[@field="ask"]/text()')
    for x in range(0,len(ask)):
        ask[x]=ask[x].replace(",",".")
        kurse[0].append(underlying[x])
        kurse[1].append(ask[x])
        kurse[2].append(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
m_kurse.append(kurse)

data = []   

a=datetime.datetime.now()
while 1:
   #try:
   getkurse(data)
   b=datetime.datetime.now()
   l=len(data)-1
   print "Data[]: ", len(data),len(data[0]), len(data[0][0]), "| " "Time expired: ", b-a

   #except:
   #data=[]
```

I hope somebody will see obvious mistakes or may recognize my problem.
I usually solve my problems by looking on forums for similar questions, but this time I couldn't get any further. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You are storing the nodes which will keep a reference to the whole tree, and it won't get cleaned up.

Comment: My tree is in a function, so it should be a local variable = cleared after every call, isn't it?

Comment: `data` will end up containing references to the nodes, which will contain references to the tree, so they won't be cleaned up until at least `data` is cleaned up.

Comment: When I print "data", it will contain strings. Am I missing something? I mean, when a list contains strings, it doesn't contain anything else, am I wrong?

Comment: What's the full error?

Comment: Where's `313` in the code? You have `9` urls.

Comment: 313 is the number of loops in the while loop before it crashes, or 313 calls of my web scraping function. I will run my code again for the full error, and let you precisely know the error lines. But all it does, is run through the Lxml module and apparently getting stuck in parse errors. Beside that, it will display the upper error lines at the end.

Comment: Watch the memory usage as it runs

Comment: You nailed it... How can Python take over 1GB of RAM for a few lists? This is insane

Comment: If you say `.append(str(ask[x]))` it won't store a reference to the tree and the garbage collector can clean it up. Same for `underlying[x]`. I don't know if that will give the values you want though.

Comment: No, it's `html.fromstring` creates a tree which doesn't get garbage collected because some parts of it are stored in `m_curse`.

Comment: This is genius! Can you post that comment as answer? I would definitely approve; the memory load disappeared. Though I don't understand how a simple variable definition will f* the whole programm. I guess the method append() must append a reference (instead of a string)? This can be really dangerous

Comment: I would write it up, but I don't think I could give enough detail for it to be a good quality answer, which is what we strive for on Stack Overflow. Maybe someone else will do it. I don't need the internet points, I'm just happy to help.

Comment: The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6418576/lxml-memory-usage-when-parsing-huge-xml-in-python) might provide insight