# Why large xml parsing is not working here as expected?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml-parsing, lxml

I have a snippet below which should take a constant memory while parsing large xmls (> 1 GB). But, it's taking a quite a lot. Can't find the flow here. Would someone help?

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import gzip
import csv
from pprint import pprint
from lxml import etree


response = urlopen("https://host/feed.xml.gz")
response = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=response)

context = etree.iterparse(response, events=("start", "end"))

context = iter(context)

_, root = next(context)

csvfile = open('output.csv', 'w', newline='')


filt = 'some keyword, more keyword' # there is about 100 approximately

filt = [i.lower() for i in filt.split(',')]

fieldnames = ['title', 'company']
writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
writer.writeheader()

for event, job in context:
    if event == "end" and job.tag == "job":
        title = job.find('title').text
        title_as_lower = title.lower()
        for f in filt:
            if f in title_as_lower:
                company = job.find('company').text
                writer.writerow({'title': title, 'company': company})
    root.clear()

csvfile.close()
```

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/6420893/494134 this answer.

Comment: @JohnGordon, well, I have suffered earlier with this problem. The issue is basically the elementtree is getting larger and larger if I don't clear it up, so the initial approach was to clear the element right after it's processed (as done in your suggested answer). But, then people find a case that, what if xml is too large even clearing each element isn't enough, the tree will grow horizontally and can still eat up memory. So, the idea was to clear the root element itself. I would be much grateful if you please mention the flow in my code. That would be a great help. Thanks.

Comment: `root` is only assigned once.  clearing it the second (or third, fourth, etc.) time won't do anything.

Comment: Some minor wonderings :
"context = iter(context)" seems useless, isn't it ?
"_, root = next(context)" seems useless, isn't it ?
The code is using "find" on a closing tag or I missed something ?
Maybe you can provide an input sample.